# Building NSS (Network security services) for Mac OS X 10.9 not working

Tags: makefile, osx-mavericks, nss, nspr

I am trying to build NSS source codes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS) version 3.15 on OS X 10.9. 
I have downloaded the NSS and NSPR package and based on the instructions I have CDed into NSS folder and entered:

```
make nss_build_all
```

The build instructions are available at: 
developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS_Sources_Building_Testing 
and 
developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS_reference/Building_and_installing_NSS/Build_instructions

however I get the following error in the middle of the Make:

```
rm -f nfspwd; cp ../../config/nfspwd.pl nfspwd; chmod +x nfspwd
rm -f /Users/Inc/Documents/third party libraries/nss-3.15 3/nss/../dist/Darwin13.0.0_DBG.OBJ/bin/nspr-config
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C pr export
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C include export
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C md export
../../../config/./nsinstall -R -m 444 ../../../../pr/include/md/_aix32.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_aix64.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_beos.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_bsdi.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_darwin.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_dgux.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_freebsd.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_hpux32.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_hpux64.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_irix32.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_irix64.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_linux.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_netbsd.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_nto.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_openbsd.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_os2.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_osf1.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_qnx.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_riscos.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_scoos.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_solaris.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_symbian.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_unixware.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_unixware7.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_win95.cfg ../../../../pr/include/md/_winnt.cfg /Users/Inc/Documents/third party libraries/nss-3.15 3/nss/../dist/Darwin13.0.0_DBG.OBJ/include/md
../../../config/./nsinstall -R -m 444 ../../../../pr/include/md/_darwin.cfg /Users/Inc/Documents/third party libraries/nss-3.15 3/nss/../dist/Darwin13.0.0_DBG.OBJ/include
mv -f /Users/Inc/Documents/third party libraries/nss-3.15 3/nss/../dist/Darwin13.0.0_DBG.OBJ/include/_darwin.cfg /Users/Inc/Documents/third party libraries/nss-3.15 3/nss/../dist/Darwin13.0.0_DBG.OBJ/include/prcpucfg.h
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
make[4]: *** [export] Error 64
make[3]: *** [export] Error 2
make[2]: *** [export] Error 2
make[1]: *** [export] Error 2
make: *** [build_nspr] Error 2
```

executing the **Make** command with **-d** would give:

```
mv -f /Users/Inc/Documents/third party libraries/nss-3.15 3/nss/../dist/Darwin13.0.0_DBG.OBJ/include/_darwin.cfg /Users/Inc/Documents/third party libraries/nss-3.15 3/nss/../dist/Darwin13.0.0_DBG.OBJ/include/prcpucfg.h
Live child 0x7fb979412400 (export) PID 51673 
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
Reaping losing child 0x7fb979412400 PID 51673 
make[4]: *** [export] Error 64
Removing child 0x7fb979412400 PID 51673 from chain.
Reaping losing child 0x7fa8597006f0 PID 51664 
make[3]: *** [export] Error 2
Removing child 0x7fa8597006f0 PID 51664 from chain.
Reaping losing child 0x7faeb8600f90 PID 51662 
make[2]: *** [export] Error 2
Removing child 0x7faeb8600f90 PID 51662 from chain.
Reaping losing child 0x7feea2504bf0 PID 51660 
make[1]: *** [export] Error 2
Removing child 0x7feea2504bf0 PID 51660 from chain.
Reaping losing child 0x7fa6f0c0bce0 PID 51650 
make: *** [build_nspr] Error 2`enter code here`
Removing child 0x7fa6f0c0bce0 PID 51650 from chain.
```

I have downloaded the package several times and performed make clean before testing..

Answer (score 0):

You should never use paths containing whitespace (or other shell-special characters) when building software with make.